# How can I use javascript to count the number of items on screen with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, css

I have found some samples online that show how to count elements with a certain class

```
document.querySelectorAll('#main-div .specific-class').length;
```

however my problem is that my class has spaces.
for example

```
class="toggle btn btn-default off"
```

How would I count these?

Comment: _Show us_ what you have found. Depending on what exact method is used to select the elements, this could possibly be very trivial.

Comment: A class name can't contain spaces, rather you've multiple classes assigned to the same element.

Comment: (And please go read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: As @Teemu said there will be multiple classes and if you want to count all the elements that has the classes `toggle btn btn-default off` you can select them with `querySelectorAll`  it will return a nodelist and you can get the length like this `document.querySelectorAll('.toggle, .btn ,.btn-default,.off').length`

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` takes a CSS selector string. You would use it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/05uecws8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#main-div .specific-class').length;
```

this will look for and find all DOM elements with class specific-class and under(doesn't matter if it is directly under or not) DOM element with id main-div.

If you want to find all elements with specific multiple classes and get length of elements, you should remove space between classes in querySelectorAll.

So if you have a HTML tag with classes

```
class="toggle btn btn-default off"
```

you should do

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('toggle.btn.btn-default.off').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let cn = "toggle btn btn-default off";
    //create div and set it's className "toggle btn btn-default off"
    let e = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.className = cn;

    // count elements where class="toggle btn btn-default off" 
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName(cn).length);
```

//1

Comment: English please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle btn btn-default off')
```

`elements` is an [*array-like object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s). Then you can use the property `length` to count the number of elements.

```
const count = elements.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the classes, if you have more than one:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#main-div.toggle.btn.btn-default.off').length;
```